# CSV file unread columns

Tags: python, csv

l m trying to get data from CSV file and there are three column ("date",stations","pcp" ) including 41 years data set. l would like to get these data separately.

example dataset:

```
  date      stations     pcp
1.01.1979   6   1.071
2.01.1979   6   5.909
3.01.1979   6   9.134
1.01.1979   5   1.229
2.01.1979   5   0.014
3.01.1979   5   3.241
```

when l run code , l got this output

```
date;stations;pcp None None
2.04.1979;6;0.0 None None
3.04.1979;6;0.0 None None
4.04.1979;6;0.35 None None
5.04.1979;5;0.003 None None
```

date field including all data but stations and pcp fields are "None"
how can l solve it?

here is my code

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('p2.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames=("date","stations","pcp"),delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
       print(row["date"],row["stations"],row["pcp"])
```

Comment: Properly paste your data here

Comment: From your output it seems delimited isnt ` ` but `;`. Thats why it got whole row under `date` and kept `stations` and `pcp` `None` as reader couldn't find any value associated with those columns.

Comment: thank you for editing. l tried to correct it but l could not do right. sorry for it

Comment: Can't you use comma(,) delimiter?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: python 3.5  version  ,l tried comma(,) and output is same

Comment: Is that the actual output? I can't see where the ";" came from. And what is the delimiter in the input csv file? looks like three spaces?

Comment: I tried your same code. I'm getting proper output. There is a problem with your input file format, the delimiter is not ' ', its multiple spaces.

Comment: you are right. l tried it on new csv file with example data  and  l got proper output. during export data , delimiter was "|" instead of ";" . l exported it again with delimiter ";" and it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file (`p2.csv`):

```
date stations pcp
1.01.1979 6 1.071
2.01.1979 6 5.909
3.01.1979 6 9.134
1.01.1979 5 1.229
2.01.1979 5 0.014
3.01.1979 5 3.241
```

Your code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('p2.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames=("date","stations","pcp"),delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
       print(row["date"],row["stations"],row["pcp"])
```

Output:

```
date stations pcp
1.01.1979 6 1.071
2.01.1979 6 5.909
3.01.1979 6 9.134
1.01.1979 5 1.229
2.01.1979 5 0.014
3.01.1979 5 3.241
```

There is a serious problem with your input file. The delimter is not a single space, it's having multiple spaces.